# ASP.NET Fire and Forget (One Way) Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, service

I've create a regular old ASMX web service in ASP.NET and added SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay = true)] to the function call as I've read this is supposed to make the call Asynchronous. However I call this in my code and it definitely does not make the call asynchronous, my page just sits there waiting for the function to finish working. What gives?

```
[SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay = true)]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void UpdateAccounts()
{
 //do work
}

//call the function
GlobalServices service = new GlobalServices();
service .UpdateAccounts()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have to make the call using the Async method.  You should make the call to `service.UpdateAccountsAsync()` in this case.

Comment: Except that the documentation for OneWay states that the web service will return an HTTP status code 202 immediately, prior to executing the service method, so I don't think making the service 
function asynchronous is going to help.

Comment: This is my understanding of how it works, or how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning a value?  The documentation for OneWay states that "fire and forget" web methods cannot return a value or have out parameters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapdocumentmethodattribute.oneway(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Nope, not returning anything.

Comment: Try removing your function and see if the web service returns. If it does, then I guess you do need to fire your service function asynchronously, as Erich stated.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the "EnableSession" attribute is somehow interfering with the asynchronous behavior.  Try removing that as well.